# certbot wildcard certificate mismatch

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am creating SSL certificate with certbot with this command:

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos -d *.foo.bar --email foo@bar.com
```

in nginx configuration I am giving fullchain.pem and priveKey.pem for SSL handshake. everything is ok with no error. but the problem is when I am trying to reach https://jjj.foo.bar it says the certificate is not trusted. but I can accept and proceed to my request. so I checked my site with **https://www.sslshopper.com/** for checking where is the issue . all of the tests are passed but common names are mismatched . why?
[image]

Comment: After executing the above command, the Certbot will share a text record to add to your DNS. Have you added that to your DNS?

Comment: @Yogeshwar yes I did it.

Comment: cool! what was the problem?